# Cómo seleccionar un item del Spinner dependiendo lo traído de consulta?

Tags: android, listview, spinner, studio, android-spinner

Tengo este Array
**String grupos[] = {"Mamífero", "Ave", "Reptil", "Anfibio", "Pez"};**

Que forma parte de una tabla. Me gustaría que cuando traiga la información de la BDD, en el Spinner quede seleccionado el grupo al que pertenece. Por ejemplo, selecciono "Especie 1", que es del grupo "Ave", en el TXT me carga "Especie 1", y que en el Spinner que carga los Grupos se seleccione "Ave".

Le cargo el Array de esta forma:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapterGrupo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, grupos);
    spinnerArrayAdapterGrupo.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerGrupo.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapterGrupo);
```

Comment: ya conectastes la BDD al spinner?

Comment: Sí, pero no sé cómo mostrar en el Spinner la opción que consigue de la BDD